# flutter reference to unspecified seems stuck at 0.3.4

Tags: dart, openid, flutter

I'm trying to add a reference to openid_client in my flutter app.

I add a dependency to openid_client: ^0.1.3 in my pubspec.yaml and save.  This runs flutter packages get, which reports the following error:

```
Package unscripted has no versions that match >=0.6.2 <0.7.0 derived from:
- openid_client 0.1.0 depends on version >=0.6.2 <0.7.0
```

Indeed, the openid_client package does depend on unscripted version 0.6.2, but my flutter app cannot reference 0.6.2.  It appears the highest version of unscripted my flutter app can reference is 0.3.4.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

This is my pubspec.yaml as it currently stands:

```
name: flit
description: A new Flutter project.

dependencies:
    flutter:
      sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
english_words: ^3.1.0
openid_client: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: `unscripted` is command-line package. It wouldn't work with Flutter. It means that `openid_client` also doesn't support Flutter.

Comment: Command line packages usually are compatible with Flutter if they don't use `dart:mirrors`

Comment: `unscripted` [depends on](https://github.com/seaneagan/unscripted/search?utf8=✓&q=mirrors&type=)  `dart:mirrors`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I didn't understand that nuance.

Comment: If anyone who maintains the dart package documentation is monitoring this thread; you may want to remove the flutter tag from packages not compatible with flutter: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/openid_client.  It might confuse people less that way...

Comment: @Mogol This page does not show a mirrors dependency: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/unscripted#-analysis-tab-.  Just for my edification, where would I see that dependency?

Comment: I found in [source code](https://github.com/seaneagan/unscripted/blob/master/lib/src/invocation_maker.dart)